# Roamingfolder.CreateFileAsync how do I close the file

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Using this code:

```
    private async void writeToStorage(string contents)
    {
        var roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
        var storFile = await roamingFolder.CreateFileAsync("test", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storFile, contents);
    }
```

Do I need to close the file? And if so.. how do I do that? There is no Close on the storFile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not need to close this file.

`StorageFolder` and `StorageFile` instances are just a pointers to a folder and a file.
Using the `WriteTextAsync` method will open/write and close automatically the stream.